# Convert decimal variable to binary variable in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

In Qiskit, there is an integrated option for converting integer variables to binary variables (*IntergertoBinary*). Is there any similar option to convert decimal variables to integer variables? Else, is any idea how to write a program for the same?
Appreciate any leads, thank you!

Comment: There are ways to do that in python.  For example, bin(3) gives you a string of '0b11'.